# Как оформить меню в WP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть меню, как ни старался - стили не подключаются, приходится инлайнить. Из-за этого, меню невозможно не выровнять в одну строку, не убрать стиль списка, ничего другого. Может ошибка в подключении?

```css
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Или в самом коде что-то не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div class="row align-items-start">
  <div class="text-light col-12" style="background-color:#1774a8; padding-left: 0.5em; display: flex; justify-content: flex-start; flex-direction: row;">
<?php
  $args = array(
  'theme_location' => 'primary_menu',      //определяем область темы где будет размещаться главное меню
  'container' => 'nav',                    //определяем родительский элемент (тег <nav>)
  'container_class' => 'nav-primary-menu', //назначаем имя класса для родительского элемента (тег <nav>)
  'menu_class' => 'ul-primary-menu'        //назначаем имя класса для меню (тег <ul>)
  );
 
  wp_nav_menu('меню два');                      //обеспечивает отображение меню
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Может ошибка в подключении?

Именно. Стили нужно подключать с помощью [wp_enqueue_style](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_style).

Например:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_style' );
function my_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/my_style.css' );
}
```